# Magento 2 change position of billing and shipping address are the same section?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, shipping-address, billing-address

We would like to change the position of `My billing and shipping address are the same` section to the top of the `payment methods` section.

Please refer attached screen shot and advise?
[image]

Comment: you can't make shipping and billing address out of payment group!! but yes you can change withing payment group means before payment methods listing you can display shipping address

Comment: hi @RutveeSojitra thank you for suggestion. i tried and found solution for this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with help of @steros answer & tried in local instance its working as expected.

> app/code/Nagaraju/ReorderBillingForm/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"> 
       <plugin name="reorder-billing-form" type="Nagaraju\ReorderBillingForm\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="25"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Nagaraju/ReorderBillingForm/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Nagaraju\ReorderBillingForm\Model\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig **/
     protected $scopeConfig;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig   
      ){  
        $this->scopeConfig=$scopeConfig;    
       }

   /**
    * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
    * @param array $jsLayout
    * @return array
    */

   public function afterProcess(
       \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
       array $jsLayout
   )
   {
       $displayBillingAddressFlag=$this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkout/options/display_billing_address_on', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES);       
       if($displayBillingAddressFlag == 1){                  
         $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];    
         unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);
        return $jsLayout;
       }else{
        return $jsLayout;
      }
   }
}
```